# Как получить непрочитанные сообщения ImapClient(GemBox.Email.Imap)?

Tags: c#, gmail, imap

Необходимо получить все сообщения с почты, которые не прочитаны, при помощи каких средств это можно сделать?
Если важно, то подключаюсь я так:

```
ComponentInfo.SetLicense("FREE-LIMITED-KEY");
imap = new ImapClient("imap.gmail.com");

// Connect to mail server
imap.Connect();
imap.Authenticate(userName,password);
imap.SelectInbox();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нашел такое решение:

```
IList<ImapMessageInfo> messagesInfo = imap.ListMessages();

foreach (var item in messagesInfo)
{
    foreach (var item1 in item.Flags)
    {
        if (item1 == "\\Seen")
        {
            //...
        }
    }              
}
```